# What does out of bound 1 means in Octave?

Tags: octave

```
%Program to compute w and r

clear

num = input("Enter your value for n: ");
n=1:num;
w(1)=8000;
for i=2:num
  w=[w(0.98*w(i-1)-250*(i-1)/((i-1)+1))];
end
r(1)=1.50*w(1); 
for i=2:num
   r=[r(1.50*w(i))];
end
format bank;
disp("N      Weight       Revenue");
disp([n', w', r']);
```

The output I am getting is:

```
A(I): Index out of bound; value 7715 out of bound 1
```

what mistake I am making here?

Comment: btw, are you using "GNURoot Octave"?

Answer (score 1):

The error message also shows the line number where the error happened which you haven't posted. it's this line

```
w=[w(0.98*w(i-1)-250*(i-1)/((i-1)+1))];
```

Here you are trying to access element 7715 (=0.98*8000-250/2) but w only has size 1x1. This always happens for out of bounds read, for example:

```
octave:> a = [5 2 3]
a =
   5   2   3
octave:> a(4)
error: A(I): index out of bounds; value 4 out of bound 3
```

Comment: It's probable that there is a missing space `w=[w (0.98...` and the same for the calculation of `r`.